# "androidx" Fragment[State]PagerAdapter fails on lollipop 5.0.1

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have an activity with 3 tabs handled by androidx FragmentPagerAdapter.
ViewPager contains a Fragment and Fragment contains some child Fragments.
App works perfectly fine on android 7+ devices but it fails on lollipop 5.0.1.

I tried using basic simple fragments to see if problem was fragment related but it was not.

```
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    try {
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            token = getArguments().getString("token");
            name = getArguments().getString("name");
            number = getArguments().getString("number");
        }
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_pending_layout, container, false);
        TextView txt_token = view.findViewById(R.id.txt_pending_token);
        TextView txt_name = view.findViewById(R.id.txt_pending_name);
        TextView txt_number = view.findViewById(R.id.txt_pending_number);
        RadioButton radio_cancel = view.findViewById(R.id.radio_cancel);
        RadioButton radio_confirm = view.findViewById(R.id.radio_confirm);
        Button btn_ok = view.findViewById(R.id.btn_pending_ok);

        txt_token.setText("Token: " + token);
        txt_name.setText("Name: " + name);
        txt_number.setText("Number: " + number);

        btn_ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
            //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "test toast", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        return view;
    } catch (Exception e){
        //StackTraceElement[] el = e.getStackTrace();
        //for(StackTraceElement elem : el){
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();//}
    return null;}
    }
```

***Error:*** Error inflating class < Unknown > on lollipop 5.0.1

***Update:*** issue seems to be with getChildFragmentManager.

Comment: Is there any stack-trace available? "Error inflating class on lollipop 5.0.1" might be a valid error description, however it is still difficult to see how/why the issue arises.

Comment: Unfortunately no as i don't currently own any lollipop devices and dont have emulater capable system to test it.